# How to use methods from NSManagedObject entity using NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am using a NSManagedObject to save some values, but not using entity for that. Because I want to not limit it to some entities. I tried using (Oist *)managedObject.entity, not working. How to use this managedObject to get theIt's like this:

```
Oist.h
@class File;

@interface Oist : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *files;
@end

@interface Oist (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFilesObject:(File *)value;

File.h
@class Oist;

@interface File : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) Oist *gist;

@end

- (void)newManagedObjectWithClassName:(NSString *)className forRecords:(NSDictionary *)records
{
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:[[GPCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];
    [records enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [self setValue:obj forKey:key forManagedObject:newManagedObject];
    }];
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key forManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{
    File *fileEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[[GPCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"files"])
    {
        NSDictionary *files = (NSDictionary *)value;
        for (NSString *key in [files allKeys]) {
            NSDictionary *file = [files valueForKey:key];
            NSLog(@"%@", file[@"filename"]);
            [fileEntity setValue:file[@"filename"] forKey:@"filename"];
            [fileEntity setValue:file[@"type"] forKey:@"type"];
        }
    } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"id"])
    {
        if ([managedObject.entity.name isKindOfClass:[Oist class]]) {
        //here I want to use Oist's method - (void)addFilesObject:(File *)value; how to do that?
        }
        [managedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value integerValue]] forKey:@"gistID"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it looks like you're hoping to cast a generically typed (NSManagedObject *) as a more specifically typed subclass.

The way to check if the pointer passed generically is in fact an instance of your subclass is this:

```
if ([managedObject isKindOfClass:[Oist self]]) {
    // managedObject may safely be cast to an Oist*
}
```

You can do the cast without an assignment, like this:

```
[(Oist *)managedObject addFiles...];
```

Or, with proper parentheses, access a property (the dot operator has higher precedence than the cast, so you need to tell the compiler you want the cast first):

```
((Oist *)managedObject).entity
```

But I think that's less clear to the reader and potentially more keystrokes than an explicit assignment with a cast, which is what I'd recommend:

```
if ([managedObject isKindOfClass:[Oist self]]) {
   Oist *oist = (Oist *)managedObject;
   [oist addFilesObject:someFilesObject];
}
```